# Case insenstive search of 2D list

Tags: python, list, path, python-itertools

I need to search a list of lists for the phrase "ss".

The problem is, it could be capitalised in any way.

With a normal list, I know that I could create a for loop, and use str.lower()

For itertools, it's less simple. There's no .lower attribute.
Here's the code so far:

```
return(ss in (itertools.chain.from_iterable(result))
```

Does anybody know a way that I can search this while ignoring case?

Comment: `"ss" or "superseded"` is only going to select `'ss'`; not doing what you think it does

Comment: ok, thanks for spotting that bug. Any tips you can offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `any()` in this case as:

```
my_ss_list = ["ss", "superseded"]
chained_list = [word.lower() for word in itertools.chain.from_iterable(result)] 
#                    ^ convert all the words to lower case

any(ss in chained_list for ss in my_ss_list)
# returns `True`/`False` based on the occurrence of any of the item
# of `my_ss_list` in `chained_list`
```

OR, you may explicitly make a check for each word without using any as:

```
"ss" in chained_list or "superseded" in chained_list
```

Comment: Thanks Moinuddin, that chained_list approach did the trick. I guess I couldn't see the trees for the forest! Thanks for the ss list as well, that bug could have caused problems later. :)